# Indicate time until queue is available again in review queues dropdown

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

There is maximum number of reviews per day per queue. Upon reaching that maximum, that particular queue is hidden from the *review queues* dropdown menu.

It would be nice to indicate in that dropdown menu how long before a queue is available again, instead of just being absent. For example, show the disabled item in gray and the amount of time left in parenthesis as indicated in the attached image.

[image: Image of proposed change.]

Comment: @rene - That would be fine. This would be a "nice to have" feature, I can't see it being a high priority.

Comment: @rene The server already has to decide that the queue is not available for this user, when it hides it from the list. The only additional computation this proposal involves is computing the time left in the current UTC day.

Comment: @Michelle ah, yes. That is correct I guess. cleaning up ...

Comment: For VLQ though, it might start off saying "(in 4 hours)" but then the queue could fill up sufficiently and you can review more again... That might be somewhat surprising behaviour...

Comment: This turns over at the same time every day (23:59UTC➞00:00UTC). Once you're aware of when that time is with respect to your local time, it's easy to know how long that's going to be by looking at a clock (e.g. as displayed on most desktop/tablets/phones).

Comment: @Michelle, Is it really something that would be done on the server? Is that the list fetched *every* time that popup is opened, or is it only fetched once per page, if the popup is opened? I believe the popup is fetched only once per page, if opened. If it's fetched once per page, then the calculation must occur in-browser in JavaScript in order to keep the countdown accurate if the popup is opened again later. This would be similar to how the JavaScript already calculates relative times for many times on the page (e.g. how long ago each comment was posted, question/answer posted/edited, etc).

Comment: @makyen - Sometimes it says come back in 4 hours, sometimes 12, sometimes 24. That's why I think the hint, as illustrated in my image would be  helpful.

Comment: @Difster It always tells you to come back at 0 UTC; that's when the review limits (and vote/flag limits) renew. If you care about review limits, all you need to know is when 0 UTC is in your timezone. That's a lot easier to remember than "today it told me to come back in 4 hours, let's mark it down somewhere".